# Custom Additional Cell Actions in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

I'd like to extend the MS Excel 2010 by adding some more "Additional Cell Actions". (accessible via cell right-click > Additional Cell Actions). Specifically, I'd like Excel to:

1. recognize five-to-eight digit numbers as Part Numbers with action: "Open URL to technical docs"
2. recognize string "OR ## #####" (# for digit) as Order Reference with actions: "Open spec file" and "Open material file" (both Excel files located at specified paths in the intranet)

Now, I have no idea how to program this. I suspect that some XML snippet is needed and probably some VB code too. VB code wouldn't be a problem - I have macros doing those functionalities done for Excel 2003 - but I have no idea where to place it.

Please give me some pointers, I've asked Google but can't get the answer, seems that "Additional Actions" is pretty common phrase :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding a right click event handler to the workbook

In the Workbook module add this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cBut As CommandBarButton
    Dim v As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    v = Target

    ' Remove any previously added menu items
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Open URL to technical docs").Delete
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Open material file").Delete

    ' save cell value for use by called macro
    CellValue = v

    ' If cell matches criteria add menu item and set macro to call on click
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        If v >= 10000 And v <= 99999999 Then
            Set cBut = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)

            With cBut
                .Caption = "Open URL to technical docs"
                .Style = msoButtonCaption
                .OnAction = "OpenRef"
            End With
        End If
    ElseIf v Like "OR ## #####" Then
        Set cBut = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)

        With cBut
            .Caption = "Open material file"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "OpenMat"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

In a standard module add this code

```
Public CellValue As Variant

' replace MsgBox code with your logic to open files
Sub OpenRef()
    MsgBox "Open Reference Doc code here for " & CellValue
End Sub

Sub OpenMat()
    MsgBox "Open Material File code here for " & CellValue
End Sub
```